# Time complexity of variable assignation

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, code-complexity

I know that if I have a function like:

```
public int addOne(int a){
    return (a+1)
}
```

The time complexity order will be O(1) since we only do one operation (the sum).

But what if I have a function that doesn't do any operations, just assigns some values to some global variables. Like this:

```
public void assignValues(){
    a = 2;
    b = 3;
    c = 4;
    //maybe more
}
```

What would the time complexity be for this function? My guess is that it would still O(1). Is that correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complexity Analysis: how to identify the "basic operation"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46168440/complexity-analysis-how-to-identify-the-basic-operation)

Answer (score 0):

When you discuss the time complexity of an algorithm, you first have to define the variable parameter(s). For example, it doesn't make any sense to say that something is `O(n)` without defining what you measure by `n` (e.g. the length of an array? The size of the contents of an array? The bit-length of a number? The absolute value of an integer?).

In your particular case, you have a function that takes no parameters. Assuming that the operations within the function don't depend on any other external parameters, the complexity of such a function is always trivially `O(1)`, no matter what operations you perform inside. For example, the following function is also `O(1)`:

```
public static int DoSth() {
  int x = 0;
  const int n = 1000000;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
      x++;
  return x;
}
```

As already mentioned, this assumes that the parameter-less function has no external dependencies. Consider e.g. the following function

```
public static void DoSth() {
  int n = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

This function is `O(n log n)` if `n` is the amount of time that has passed since 1.1.0001.